# how to make text next to an image

Tags: html, css

## Hey there!

I am really new to stack overflow, not *very* new, because I have used the program before, so please tell me if i need to fix anything or something I can improve apon!

So here is my task:

I want to place text here:

```
[image] text
[image]
[image]
```

but using `float:right;` does this:

```
[image]               text
[image]
[image]
```

and adding `padding:{num}px;` makes it like this:

```
[image]
[image]
[image]
                                               text
```

and any thing I try yields the same results. Is there way to do this?

### OTHER

I have tried using this: `<h1><img src="image.png">Text</h1>` but that does this:

```
[image]
[image]
[image]text
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this:

```css
.imageflex { display: flex; }
.imageflexcontent { margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="imageflex">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487111023822-2e903e12f6f0?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80" height="280px">

  <p class="imageflexcontent">Photo by <a href="https://unsplash.com/@filipz?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Filip Zrnzević</a> on <a href="https://unsplash.com/s/photos/forest?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Unsplash</a></p>
</div>
```

Basically, put a flexbox around your image and text and it should have the layout you would like. You can change the margins if you would like the text to be more seperated.

If it doesn't work, you can do it with an inline block around the text, though it would be harder to get the results you are looking for.

```
display: inline-block
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left` on the image. This will allow text right next to it.

Comment: thanks for you feedback! But it didnt work :( it has the same result as doing `<h1><img src="image.png">Text</h1>`

Comment: Also I didn't mean anything negative towards you answer! I am sorry if it came across that way.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top` should do it.

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
  <p class="text">Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I really needed this :)

Comment: Glad this helps. If this answered your question, please consider upvoting / marking as answer. This lets future readers know if an answer is helpful. Have a good day!